# Set Graphic to label

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to set Label to graphic. I tested this code:

```
    private static final ImageView livePerformIcon;

        static
        {
            livePerformIcon = new ImageView(MainApp.class.getResource("/images/Flex.jpg").toExternalForm());
        }

final Label label = new Label();
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"/images/Flex.jpg\");");

            livePerformIcon.setFitHeight(20);
            livePerformIcon.setFitWidth(20);
            label.setGraphic(livePerformIcon);
```

But I don't see any image.

The only way that I found to make it work is this:

```
label.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"/images/Flex.jpg\");");
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Please debug your code. Is livePerformIcon not null if label.SetGraphic(livePerformIcon); is called?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but AFAIK controls should be created on the JavaFX Application thread, but you're creating ImageView in a static initializer, which I'm not sure if it's executed on the Application thread.

Besides: Do you really want livePerformIcon to be static???

Comment: Yes I use it in static Java method.

Answer (score 0):

This one made from the data used in the docs, works perfectly for me

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabelWithImages extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Label With Image Sample");
    stage.setWidth(400);
    stage.setHeight(180);

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    //Replace the image you want to put up
    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("a.png"));
    Label label = new Label("Demo Label");
    label.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
    hbox.setSpacing(10);
    hbox.getChildren().add((label));
    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(hbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippets below will set the value of the property graphic of a label. You can use any of the two. I prefer using javafx css, just to implement the model-view-controller design.

```
// programmatically, provided with image input stream
label.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/image.png"))));

// javafx css, provided with image url
.label {
    -fx-graphic: url("path/to/image.png");
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.